# Is there a way to have two commands with the same name?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to make a bot that says hi when someone says hi. I also want it to say hello. its just a project to make myself more familiar with discord.py but i cant use both. for example, i have code below that makes the bot say hi if someone else says hi, but i also want to do it for hello. now neither works because they both have the name on_message. i dont want to use commands (i have reasons but just trust me on this) so is there any way to do this?

```
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged on as {client.user}!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('hi'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('hi')
```

Comment: Those aren't commands. You're writing code inside of `on_message`. And no, you get one `on_message`. Do both checks inside of the one function; you can't have two functions with the same name and expect them both to keep working.

Comment: Why `on_message`? And yes, you can just put two if blocks to do it. If you want an efficient way to use commands, try the commands extension.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well,
you can not put two functions with the same name.

If you want to do this you will can try create a command.

You can create one like this:

```
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged on as {client.user}!')

@client.command
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("Hello!")
@client.command
async def hi(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("hi!")
```

To make this answer to a prefix put this as you client:

```
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='your prefix', case_insensitive=True)
```

If you absolutly have to not put commands I suggest you try this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('hi'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('hi')
    elif message.content.startswith('hello'):
         channel = message.channel
         await channel.send('hello')
```

though i'm not sure this will work